# What is valid timing of using current_user_can() and related functions?

Tags: capabilities, permissions

During the vanilla WP core load the current user is being set up in `$wp-init()` which is after theme load and before `init` hook. This is in line with good practice of functionality getting hooked to `init` or later.

However it is also common practice to call related functions, such as `current_user_can()` *earlier* than that. It is by definition required for plugins that work with earlier stages of load process (my Toolbar Theme Switcher plugin would be an example).

Documentation makes no claims for or against this practice (that I could find).

However some plugins seem to hook into user–related functionality and expect the post–`init` state at all times.

For example bbPress throws following notice:

```
// If the current user is being setup before the "init" action has fired,
// strange (and difficult to debug) role/capability issues will occur.
if ( ! did_action( 'after_setup_theme' ) ) {
    _doing_it_wrong( __FUNCTION__, __( 'The current user is being initialized without using $wp->init().', 'bbpress' ), '2.3' );
}
```

For quick demonstration throw this into core's definition of `current_user_can()`:

```
function current_user_can( $capability ) {

    if ( ! did_action('after_setup_theme') ) {
        echo wp_debug_backtrace_summary();
    }
```

Who is “right” in this situation? Is there a canonical determination about allowed / forbidden usage of user–related functions before `init` ?

Comment: See also https://codex.bbpress.org/bbp_setup_current_user/was-called-incorrectly/

Answer (score 7):

The only prerequisite for `current_user_can()` is an existing `wp_get_current_user()`. The latter is defined in `pluggable.php`, so you can use it after `plugins_loaded`.

The `_doing_it_wrong()` call you are citing in your question is wrong for itself. My guess is that you took that from BuddyPress or bbPress. Both are running into a recursion if they don't wait that long. There are other, better ways to prevent the recursion.

In some cases, like [changing the locale](https://github.com/inpsyde/multilingual-press/issues/88), you *have* to access the current user object earlier, so waiting for `after_setup_theme` isn't even an option.

Comment: See also https://codex.bbpress.org/bbp_setup_current_user/was-called-incorrectly/

Answer (score 2):

If you check user capability before `init` means there're chances *you* are the responsible for the setting of the current user object.

If you access user *after* `init`, then you are sure that *something else* already setup the user, most the times core itself.

This is why accessing user after `init` is considered *safe*.

In fact, early access may possibly break some filter running on `determine_current_user`.

It worth saying that one is a "fragile" hook, because there're chances it never runs, being fired only in pluggable functions.

However, there are cases (like **@toscho** said) where you *can't* wait until init, in those cases you have no choice.

Only way to solve any incompatibility is case by case, if you have will.

A solution that *may* work in most cases (including bbPress / BuddyPress) is to use following function instead of `current_user_can`:

```
function compat_current_user_can( $capability )
{
  if ( did_action( 'init' ) ) {
     return current_user_can( $capability );
  }

  $user_id = apply_filters( 'determine_current_user', false );

  return user_can( $user_id, $capability );
}
```

This allows to check current user capability early without setting global user, so *in theory* safe to be run before `init`.

Problem is that, as said above, any code that overrides pluggable functions and not fires `determine_current_user` breaks it.

Comment: I think your function has variables tad messed up. :)

Comment: Yes... typed too fast before dinner :P thanks @ialocin for fixing.

Comment: Don't mention it. Besides don't just tell what is wrong, fix it @Rarst :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm inclined to think that BuddyPress and bbPress should be checking something else  before issuing the `_doing_it_wrong` message

I changed both routines to also check the actual setting of $current_user.

```
global $current_user; 
if ( is_null( $current_user ) ) {
    _doing_it_wrong( ... );
}
```

The Notices were no longer displayed.

The testing for `did_action( "after_setup_theme" )` becomes the braces to go with the belt.